# Restore user login after tomcat 7 restart

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, authentication, tomcat7

The default behaviour of tomcat sessions is to persist them on shutdown and restore them after startup. This works on my simple test application as expected.
But when I add form based authentication the user login (User principal) won't get restored on tomcat restart.

Even the example application located under /examples/jsp/security/protected/index.jsp does not restore the login.

Is there any way to achieve session/authentication restoration **without** clustering/replication as suggested elsewhere?

I am using Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not archive that with tomcat and standard form based authentication at the example (it uses UserDatabaseRealm).
Take a look at the notes:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

"The cached user is not saved and restored across sessions serialisations." with all realm implementations but "JAASRealm", or so says documentation.

So you can implement your own JAAS login module to be used with forms authentication in tomcat or you can use a framework as "spring security", there are very simple tutorials on the web, for example http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

I have successfuly tested that example (the session login is remembered after tomcat restart).

I hope this help you.

Regards,
José

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hoped that there is a way around adding a huge framework just to preserve the user sessions. Spring security depends on the spring framework so is not an option for my project.

Comment: You can use Spring Security w/o integrating with Spring MVC also new namespace based configuration is pretty simple compared to older version. Give it a try and get back if u need any help.

Comment: Protection against attacks like session fixation, clickjacking, cross site request forgery, etc (as stated in www.spring.io) are some additional features u will benefit from.

Comment: As @M4ver1k said, give it a try as there is a lot of benefit when using a so heavily tested and wide used framework (although I understand you). Anyway, you can always write your own filters and authentication mechanisms storing needed data at user session (remember: any classes at session must be serializable). Digging around a little in the internet you can find some solutions so you do not have to start from scratch (for example http://sourceforge.net/projects/securityfilter/, change DefaultPersistentLoginManager to store data at session and not with cookies). Thanks to the Java community!!

Comment: Did anyone ever prove the JAASRealm logs users back in across restarts?