# Tomcat logs user out during session failover event and restarts

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee, session-replication

We've implemented session replication using Redisson, but we noticed that if we intentionally fail a node, the user's sessions do get replicated, but they're logged out when they're restored on the new server.

This answer here: [Restore user login after tomcat 7 restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825731/restore-user-login-after-tomcat-7-restart?rq=1) alludes that using the JAASRealm will allow someone to stay logged in across a restart.

To test this, I setup the JAAS Realm in Tomcat successfully using the properties login module. However, when I restart, the user gets logged out. I do see my sessions get written to disk by tomcat in it's work directory.

Is there a way to make this work properly so the user doesn't get logged out during a failover event? More importantly, is there a technical or security reason for this?

If you look at the Tomcat code, they *actively* try and avoid serialization the Principal:

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java#L1559

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java#L234